# What is the "only" argument of pm2-docker for?

Tags: node.js, docker, process, containers, pm2

`pm2-docker` is supposed to run inside docker containers, so...according to http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/:

> To split each processes in his own Docker, you can use the –only [app-name] option:
>
> CMD ["pm2-docker", "process.yml", "--only", "APP"]

What is this `--only` option for?

"Split each process in his own Docker". ? His own Docker what? Container?

So `pm2-docker` runs inside a container and spawns containers inside of it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can specify several services on the process.yml file, and this flag will only start that one specified with `--only`. It has nothind to do with docker or containers since it's also a `pm2` argument.